# How can I make the tabs transparent in Ionic 2?

Tags: css, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 and I need to make the Tabs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/) transparent or change the opacity level to have a translucent effect while scrolling a list of cards. I've tried modifying via CSS a lot of elements (tabs itself, their parents and children) but no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the classes directly you need to add

```
.md,.ios,.wp{}
```

in order to override the ionic based styles in the build. So it would be something like

```
.md,.ios,.wp{
    ion-tabs{
        opacity:0.4;
    }
}
```

You could also try creating a sass variable in `theme/variables.scss` file. And then apply that color on the color attribute.

```
 $colors:{
 ...
  tabs-color :  rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 }

 ----
 <ion-tabs color="tabs-color">
```

Comment: It didn't work. http://nimb.ws/fTLnRi I've tried several solutions like this, but they just fade the tabs / tabs bar instead of making them transparent so I can see the cards in the background.

Comment: Sadly, yes. They page structure is a bit tricky but what makes it more difficult to understand is that applying `background: transparent / opacity: .1` to every layer of the tabs bar, including the buttons, doesn't make it work either.

Comment: Nope, it just changed the tabs color http://nimb.ws/67yZKH and looks like it didn't take the alpha. I've tried a solution similar to this one I found in a Ionic forum but applying it to other layers and didn't work either.